# Pull List of COM Add-ins Available in Excel w/ Python Library

Tags: python, excel, pywin32, win32com

I'm trying to build out a process to refresh a series of excel documents on a monthly basis. One part of this process will require refreshing data from an Excel Add-In (In my case this is an add-in called SmartView).

I can't find any info on how to pull a list of add-ins accessible to the pywin32 module. Is there a way to access and iterate through a list of Add-Ins?

Here's what I know works if you know the name of the Add-In:

```
import win32com.client as win32

xl = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')

helloWorldAddIn = xl.COMAddIns("HelloWorld") # HelloWorld is the name of my AddIn.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Application.COMAddIns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.comaddins) is actually a collection of [COMAddIn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.comaddin) objects, so you can iterate over the list of available add-ins like:

```
import win32com.client as win32

xl = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')

for addin in xl.COMAddIns:
    print(addin.description)
```

Comment: That was it! Thanks Garett